# .htaccess rewrite not working?

Tags: configuration, opensuse, php, apache-virtualhost, mod-rewrite

I have the following virtual host in /etc/apache2/vhosts.d/ip-based_vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost test.local:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@test.local
ServerName test.local
DocumentRoot /home/web/test.net/html

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/test-error.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/test-access.log combined

HostnameLookups Off
UseCanonicalName Off
ServerSignature On

<Directory "/home/web/test.net/html">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All

  <IfModule !mod_access_compat.c>
  Require all granted
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule mod_access_compat.c>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  </IfModule>
  DirectoryIndex index.php
</Directory>
<IfModule proxy_fcgi_module>
  ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/home/web/test.net/html/$1
 </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

And in /home/web/test.net/html I have:

**.htacess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
```

When I visit http://test.local I get correctly "/" (without quotes).

But when I visit anything else, e.g. http://test.local/abc I get a 404 page instead of "/abc".

How can I solve this to work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check:

- whether the `.htaccess` file has proper permissions
- whether `mod_rewrite` is enabled

Comment: Thank you! mod_rewrite was disabled. After enabling it everything works fine.